# Remove duplicates from CSV file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I have an assignment where i have to read a CSV file containing data with some repeated lines. How to remove the duplicate values and print only the unique values in Eclipse

The data is similar to this:-

```
1,Ron,1234,ABC,12

2,Harry,4125,DEF,14

3,Kent,1786,GHI,15 

1,Ron,1234,ABC,12

2,Harry,4125,DEF,14
```

Comment: I am a novice to java so please help me out

Comment: create a comparison method and just compare the values... print out only the ones that are unique and that's it

Comment: Using Eclipse to develop doesn't have any bearing on the problem -it's a Java problem. You need to show some effort and where things went wrong, then people will be more willing to help.

Answer (score 4):

```
String csvFile = "csv.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lines.add(line)) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

It may help you

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the following strategy:

1st step: create a HashMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html 
where you will save each line of the CSV you read. You will save in a hashmap because Hashmap will NOT accept a key that is like another. So, each line you will read, you will save in the hashmap as a KEY!
So, the logic is: Try to save the line you just read as a Key. IF it works, print that line. If it didn't work, discard the line and read the next one.

Got it?

2nd step:
Use a BufferedReader http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedReader.html to read line by line of the CSV.
Get each line of the CSV with the BufferedReader with readLine().
It will save the line you are reading in a String

That's it.

So, here is the overview of the entire code:

1- Read each line of the code with BufferedReader.readLine()

2- Get that string you got from readLine and try to add to your Hashmap as the Key of the hashmap: if it works, print the String. If it doesn't work, discard the string;

3- Read the next line.